# Python program using class programs to simulate the roll of two dice

Tags: python, class, dice

My program is supposed to simulate to both simulate the role of a single dice and the role of two dices but I am having issues. Here is what my code looks like:

```
import random

#Dice class simulates both a single and two dice being rolled
#sideup data attribute with 'one'

class Dice:
    #sideup data attribute with 'one'

    def __init__(self):
        self.sideup='one'
    def __init__(self):
        self.twosides='one and two'

 #the toss method generates a random number
 #in the range of 1 through 6.


    def toss(self):
        if random.randint(1,6)==1:
            self.sideup='one'
        elif random.randint(1,6)==2:
            self.sideup='two'
        elif random.randint(1,6)==3:
            self.sideup='three'
        elif random.randint(1,6)==4:
            self.sideup='four'
        elif random.randint(1,6)==5:
            self.sideup='five'
        else:
            self.sideup='six'
    def get_sideup(self):
        return self.sideup
    def doubletoss(self):
        if random.randint(1,6)==1 and random.randint(1,6)==2:
            self.twosides='one and two'
        elif random.randint(1,6)==1 and random.randint(1,6)==3:
            self.twosides='one and three'
        elif random.randint(1,6)==1 and random.randint(1,6)==4:
            self.twosides='one and four'
        elif random.randint(1,6)==1 and random.randint(1,6)==5:
            self.twosides='one and five'
        elif random.randint(1,6)==1 and random.randint(1,6)==6:
            self.twosides='one and six'
        elif random.randint(1,6)==1 and random.randint(1,6)==1:
            self.twosides='one and one'
    def get_twosides(self):
        return self.twosides






#main function
def main():
    #create an object from the Dice class
    my_dice=Dice()


    #Display the siide of the dice is factory
   print('This side is up',my_dice.get_sideup())

    #toss the dice
    print('I am tossing the dice')
    my_dice.toss()

    #toss two dice
    print('I am tossing two die')
    my_dice.doubletoss()

   #Display the side of the dice that is facing up
    print('this side is up:',my_dice.get_sideup())

    #display both dices with the sides of the dice up
    print('the sides of the two dice face up are:',my_dice.get_twosides())



main()
```

Here is the output of my program when I run it:

> "Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/Pentazoid/Desktop/PythonPrograms/DiceClass.py", line 79, in 
>       main()
>     File "C:/Users/Pentazoid/Desktop/PythonPrograms/DiceClass.py", line 61, in main
>       print('This side is up',my_dice.get_sideup())
>     File "C:/Users/Pentazoid/Desktop/PythonPrograms/DiceClass.py", line 32, in get_sideup
>       return self.sideup
>
> AttributeError: 'Dice' object has no attribute 'sideup'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just to remind. Accepting correct answers is considered polite on SO. Every asker can accept one answer under his question despite of the reputation (it's not the same as upvoting). You have a check box under voting buttons of the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You have two **init** methods.  The second replaces the first, which negates your definition of sideup.

change to:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.sideup='one'
    self.twosides='one and two'
```